# Creepy Horror film with one crewmate/character being grabbed by tentacle worms that engulf his limbs

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror, space

Like the title says, I vividly remember this Sci-Fi/Thriller/Horror movie where its a group of characters escaping through a room similar to the trash compactor on the Death Star (Star Wars), but when they get to an escape hatch/ladder, one of the crew is grabbed by these large dark brown worm creatures that grab each leg, then arms, and finally his head and he is pulled under.

It's the only scene I remember vividly seeing when I was young and it couldn't have been later than the early 2000's. It felt like it was from the 80's or 90's. It was not Leviathan because the creature was different, these tentacles might have been a secondary creature and not the main antagonist.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where did you see this?  TV, video, theatre?  What country was it, and what language was the movie in?

Comment: Could it be [Deep Rising](https://youtu.be/now9X9GidV4?t=4763)?

Comment: Thank you, I had found it in an unexpected place, it was King Kong of all films.

Comment: You should post this as an answer instead of editing the answer in the question.

Answer (score 3):

As a placeholder, the querent realized they were looking for the 2005 *[King Kong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King_Kong_(2005_film))* remake.

> .... The remaining party members continue through the jungle when Kong attacks, making them fall into a ravine resulting in Hayes' death and Carl losing his camera. Kong rescues Ann from three Tyrannosaurus-like Vastatosaurus rex, bringing her to his den in the mountains. The remaining rescue party are attacked by giant insects in the ravine, resulting in the death of three more crew members, but Preston, Carl, Jack, and Hayes' apprentice Jimmy are rescued by Baxter and Englehorn....

### Bug scene

Comment: Feel free to borrow any and all of my answer and I'll delete mine.